# Android Automotive App that uses vehicle api, createCar() shows an Error

Tags: android, api, android-studio, emulation, android-automotive

I wanted to use some car data using vehicle API that is available in AA Emulator.

For that purpose, I used createCar that creates new Car object which is connected synchronously to Car Service and ready to use.

However when I use this part of code:

```
car = Car.createCar(this, null, CAR_WAIT_TIMEOUT_WAIT_FOREVER) { car:Car, ready: Boolean ->
    if (ready) {
        //Car service is available
        onCarServiceReady()
    }
}
```

*The function `onCarServiceReady()` contains code for the access to the CarPropertyManager.*

After ´Run´, I get an error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxxxxxx.apiagent, PID: 29930
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method createCar(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/Handler;JLandroid/car/Car$CarServiceLifecycleListener;)Landroid/car/Car; in class Landroid/car/Car; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.car.Car' appears in /system/framework/android.car.jar)
```

I managed to make it work using **deprecated** approach:

```
car = Car.createCar(this, object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(componentName: ComponentName, iBinder: IBinder) {
        onCarServiceReady()
    }
    override fun onServiceDisconnected(componentName: ComponentName) {
        // on failure callback
    }
})
```

Since this way is deprecated, I would love to make it work using the code that shows me an error...

What should I change to make it work, and why actually the first solution does not work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off the cuff, it feels like your AA emulator is running an older version of Automotive, one that does not have the new `createCar()` method. I have not worked with Automotive, so I am not familiar with how they handle OS and SDK versioning.